# Sharing excel file with database connections

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I have an Excel file with active database conections (OLE DB to MS SQL Server).

How can I share my file to my coworkers with that connections? I have tried to run this file on other computer, but connections cannot be refreshed because of connection problem.

Comment: Are you using a `DSN (ODBC Data Sources Admin)` created on your local machine? If so, they need to have the same `DSN` created on their local machines, then it should work.

Comment: I don't know - is it that DSN default Excel mechanism? I just created connection with database by `Data->Get External Data->From Other Sources->From SQL Server`

Comment: Ok. What did you call that connection? It is saved as a `.odbc` file in `My Documents\My Data Sources`. You could copy that file to their computers and then they might be able to open the excel file.